# Waiting for a particular spec file to execute before running another - Jasmine/Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, wait

Tools:  Protractor 3.3.0, Jasmine 2.4.1, Selenium Standalone Server.

I have a test suite that has a plethora of spec.js files each containing unique tests for my application.

I'm using the **maxInstances** and **shardTestFiles** browser capabilities to launch 3 browsers and run each spec file to decrease the run time of the entire suite (with the 3 browsers its at about 20 minutes.. so without it's probably pushing over an hour).

My question is how can I tell Protractor to have a spec file wait for the completion of another spec file before executing.  For example:

Lets say I have a **Page 1 Tests** and I have spec files **a1.spec**, **a2.spec**, and **a3.spec** and then I have some other tests of similar structure or what have you.

When I launch protractor with 3 browser instances, as expected, **a1.spec**, **a2.spec**, and **a3.spec** all launch with their own individual browser instance since it's a 1:1 ratio.  BUT what if **a3.spec** can't run unless **a2.spec** completes?  How do I make this wait occur, or is it just a best practice to not make certain tests dependent on each other?

Comment: Personally I try to make all my specs independent of each other.  I don't know about "waiting" for a particular spec, but as far as I know Protractor does execute tests  according to the alphabetical order of your suites.  That's a possibility for you, however this would be unnecessarily difficult to keep up as you keep adding specs... If they're dependent I'd probably just combine them into one larger E2E scenario

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's kind of my exact thought process so far.  I know the tests are executed alphabetically,  but even still with the way I shard the test files and use multiple browser instances, it would still be possible for something named 'z.spec' to run before 'a.spec' finished.  I'm trying to avoid using as many dependencies and dummy data as possible.  Seems like my best bet so far is to make the larger E2E file and kind of do an add, edit, remove process all in one.

thanks again!

Comment: I would definitely design the tests with parallel execution in mind. I am running my tests  in 10 parallel instances using docker and I had to make sure they didn't collide with other tests. If you are waiting for tests to end before starting new tests then you are losing a lot of the benefits of parallel execution. I am running my tests in 10 parallel instances in chrome first and once the instance finishes the specs in chrome it runs them in firefox so I don't have the same tests running at the same time.

Comment: @sonhu How are you defining it to run firefox right after chrome? or are you just manually doing that with different config settings?

Comment: You will need to use grunt and a grunt plugin named concurrent. It's not necessarily an answer to this specific question but it will give you much more control than relaying solely on protractor. I have an example that you can use as a point of reference. HTTP://www.github.com/sonhu/protractor-example most of the logic is in the grunt and conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `done` callback either in the `beforeEach` or `it` of any test which needs time to complete asynchronously. Any following tests won't run until the one you're waiting on has finished.

#### beforeEach Example

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        value = 0;
        done();
    }, 1);
});
```

#### it Example

```
it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    value++;
    expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    done();
});
```

This would queue as you need but the tests would be run serially. To speed this up you could use Promises and [when/guard](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#whenguard) but this may complicate things too much.